# Passing route params in vue router v-link

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have this anchor in Parent.vue:

```
<a v-link="{ path: '/somepath/somesubpath', query: { messageId: 999}}"> Here </a>
```

or also this

```
<a v-link="{ path: '/somepath/somesubpath', params: { messageId: 999}}"> Here </a>
```

My Child.vue is like this:

```
<template>
    {{messageId}}
    // other html..
</template>

<script>
   export default {
        props: ['messageId']
   }
</script>
```

In Child.vue I can not see the value of {{messageId}} being rendered. This means that the value is not getting passed.
I am using vue router 0.7.5 and the docs [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/v0.7.5/docs/en/link.md) do not specify how to specify params in v-link (without named routes).

So whats the proper way to pass in params using vue router with v-link?

Comment: Shouldn't you just be using `this.$route.params.messageId`?

Comment: @ceejayoz you mean `{{this.$route.params.messageId}}`? (this does not work

Comment: `this` is implied in a `{{ }}` tag. Try `{{ $route.params.messageId }}`. It'd be `this.$route.params.messageId` within the `<script>`.

Comment: @ceejayoz does not work. It seems that I am not passing data in a tag's v-link itself in correct way :(

Answer (score 2):

Route params are available in the `this.$route.params` property. They do not need to be passed as a component property.

In your case you can access the `messageId` param in your template like so:

```
{{ $route.params.messageId }}
```

However, you also need to make sure that the template for your `Child.vue` component has a single root element and not just text. Otherwise, the component will not render.

So, you'd at least need something like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ $route.params.messageId }}
  </div>
</template>
```

---

Here's a simple example:

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: `
    <div>
      message id: {{ $route.params.messageID }}
    </div>
  `
});

const Home = { 
  template: '<div>Home</div>' 
};

const Message = { 
  template: `
    <div>
      <span>Message View</span> 
      <child></child>
    </div>
  ` 
};

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Home, name: 'home' },
    { path: '/message', component: Message, name: 'message' }
  ]
})

new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <router-link :to="{ name: 'home' }">home</router-link>
  <router-link :to="{ name: 'message', params: { messageID: 123 } }">message view</router-link>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```